# How do i add CIFilter to video file imported from gallery

Tags: swift, video, filter, cifilter, avasset

What is the best approach to add filters to video files?
Do i have to extract all frames from the video and then add filter to each frame? Or is there a better approach to this.

Came across this, but not sure how to use it

```
    let vidComp = AVVideoComposition(asset: self.asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: {
     request in
    })
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a long process. Are you sitting comfortably? Then I'll begin...

As part of my [VideoEffects](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/VideoEffects/tree/master) project, I've created a class named [FilteredVideoVendor](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/VideoEffects/blob/master/VideoEffects/FilteredVideoVendor.swift), this vends filtered image frames from a movie file.

The first job of the vendor class is to actually open a movie from a URL supplied by the "load" button in the control panel:

```
func openMovie(url: NSURL){
player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

guard let player = player,
  currentItem = player.currentItem,
  videoTrack = currentItem.asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first else {
    fatalError("** unable to access item **")
}

currentURL = url
failedPixelBufferForItemTimeCount = 0

currentItem.addOutput(videoOutput)

videoTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(videoTrack.preferredTransform)

player.muted = true

}
```

There are a few interesting points here: firstly, I reset a variable named `failedPixelBufferForItemTimeCount` - this is a workaround for what I think is a bug in AVFoundation with videos that would occasionally fail to load with no apparent error. Secondly, to support both landscape and portrait videos, I create an inverted version of the video track's preferred transform.

The vendor contains a `CADisplayLink` which invokes `step(_:)`:

```
func step(link: CADisplayLink) {
guard let player = player,
  currentItem = player.currentItem else {
    return
}

let itemTime = videoOutput.itemTimeForHostTime(CACurrentMediaTime())

displayVideoFrame(itemTime)

let normalisedTime = Float(itemTime.seconds / currentItem.asset.duration.seconds)

delegate?.vendorNormalisedTimeUpdated(normalisedTime)

if normalisedTime >= 1.0
{
  paused = true
}
}
```

With the `CADisplayLink`, I  calculate the time for the `AVPlayerItem` based on `CACurrentMediaTime`. The normalised time (i.e. between 0 and 1) is calculated by dividing the player item's time by the assets duration, this is used by the UI components to set the scrub bar's position during playback. Creating a `CIImage` from the movie's frame at `itemTime` is done in `displayVideoFrame(_:)`:

```
func displayVideoFrame(time: CMTime) {
guard let player = player,
  currentItem = player.currentItem where player.status == .ReadyToPlay && currentItem.status == .ReadyToPlay else {
    return
}

if videoOutput.hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime(time) {
  failedPixelBufferForItemTimeCount = 0

  var presentationItemTime = kCMTimeZero

  guard let pixelBuffer = videoOutput.copyPixelBufferForItemTime(
    time,
    itemTimeForDisplay: &presentationItemTime) else {
      return
  }

  unfilteredImage = CIImage(CVImageBuffer: pixelBuffer)

  displayFilteredImage()
}
else if let currentURL = currentURL where !paused {
  failedPixelBufferForItemTimeCount += 1

  if failedPixelBufferForItemTimeCount > 12 {
    openMovie(currentURL)
  }
}
}
```

Before copying a pixel buffer from the video output, I need to ensure one is available. If that's all good, it's a simple step to create a `CIImage` from that pixel buffer. However, if `hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime(_:)` fails too many times (12 seems to work), I assume AVFoundation has silently failed and I reopen the movie.

With the populated `CIImage`, I apply a filter (if there is one) and return the rendered result back to the delegate (which is the main view) to be displayed:

```
func displayFilteredImage() {
guard let unfilteredImage = unfilteredImage,
  videoTransform = videoTransform else {
    return
}

let ciImage: CIImage

if let ciFilter = ciFilter {
  ciFilter.setValue(unfilteredImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

  ciImage = ciFilter.outputImage!.imageByApplyingTransform(videoTransform)
}
else {
  ciImage = unfilteredImage.imageByApplyingTransform(videoTransform)
}

let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(
  ciImage,
  fromRect: ciImage.extent)

delegate?.finalOutputUpdated(UIImage(CGImage: cgImage))
}
```

If you want to write a filtered movie back to the file system, I discuss that in [this blog post](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/loading-filtering-saving-videos-in-swift.html).

Simon